# How do I git stash with Visual Studio Tools for Git v0.8.5.1

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I am comfortable with the command line, but I'd like to know if it's possible (and if so, how) to do a git stash using [Visual Studio Tools for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading through the Q&A for the Visual Studio Tools for Git they responded that it is currently not implemented.

[Visual Studio Tools For Git Q&A](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c/view/Discussions/4#8860)

Answer (score 1):

The `git stash` feature is announced to be implemented in Visual Studio 2019. Finally.